# Using plot titles in other languages

Tags: r, non-english

Macs and androids have non-english keyboards that are easy to integrate and use.

How to use non-english, non-latin scripts in plots?

```
plot(1:10,main="हिन्दी नाम")
```

This gives me empty boxes at title (latest Rstudio on latest mac).

Comment: plot(1:10,main="हिन्दी नाम") works fine on ubuntu

Comment: Worked for me on Windows.

Comment: Somehow doesn't work on Mac :(

Answer (score 0):

After some (more) trial and error, here is a possible direction:

```
par(family="Kohinoor Devanagari")
plot(1:10,main="हिन्दी नाम")
```

This does the job somewhat! But not quite satisfactory as the words don't show up properly.